# Need highlighting for the Stack Exchange notifications

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, notifications, highlighting

This is about the Stack Exchange link on the top-left corner of the screen. It shows the number of new posts/comments with a tiny red circle, but when I click on the link, it shows a list of the new posts/comments **and** the old ones.
The problem with the list is that when there are multiple comments to a single question, it becomes hard to differentiate between which notifications are new and which are old.

Could the new notifications be highlighted in the list so it becomes easier to locate?

EDIT: Screenshot: [image: Highlighting]

Comment: @Jeff I think this is still a problem, based on the comments on my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new notifications are *already* highlighted, just very dimly -- I was part way through writing this exact [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) once before I realized it. I ended up writing a greasemonkey script that changed the highlight color:

```
var css = document.createElement("style");
css.type = "text/css";
css.textContent = ".itemBoxNew {background-color: #aaffaa !important;}";
document.body.appendChild(css);
```

[image: Screenshot of my inbox color]

Comment: @Michael: Ok...cool! It was easy to notice here on meta. Wonder why I didn't notice it while I was on SO.

Comment: If the only thing this script to is to inject some styles, then why not just use a userstyle instead?

Comment: @YiJiang Because I don't even know what a user style is. I know exactly enough Javascript and GM commands to write the scripts I want, and generally no more, so I doubt any of my scripts do things the ideal way

Comment: @Michael: I logged in twice to Stack Overflow today, and both times I had new comments in the stackExchange box, but both times the background was not highlighted. Not even dimly.

Comment: @Nav Can you get a screenshot of this one? This is what it [looks like normally](http://so.mrozekma.com/inbox-highlight-original.png)

Comment: @Michael: Well right now when I checked, it worked. I'll just try it a couple of times more and see when the problem happens.

Comment: @Michael: Okay, I've got a screenshot. Seems like the highlight went onto the main page instead of the StackExchange box. I had added the screenshot gif to my question. I'm not able to see it though. Can you see it?

Comment: @Nav The highlight on the main page is because that post is tagged [c++], which is one of your frequented tags. I'm not sure why the highlight suddenly didn't show up, I've never seen that before

Comment: @Michael: Could it be because of greasemonkey conflict? I use a greasemonkey script to remove the Wikipedia Donation ads.

Comment: @Nav Seems pretty unlikely

Comment: Ok, asked question on SO and got 1 answer. Clicked the stackExchange box. No highlight. Refreshed page later. There were two more answers (shown as red circle with a 2 at the centre). Clicked SE box. Highlight was present for both. Opened a new tab in firefox. Refreshed both tabs a while later. Both pages showed 1 new red circle in inbox. Clicked the SE box of first tab. Highlight was present. Clicked SE box in second box of second tab. Highlight not present (normal). The only malfunction appears to be when I first log in and there's no highlight. Afterward everything seems to work correctly.

Comment: Just following up. It works fine now. Thanks :)